# XNA Update() function update rate, varies greatly on different machines

Tags: xna, emulation

I'm coding an emulator in XNA. The emulator's accuracy depends greatly on real fps. The fps must be 60 per second. While Microsoft claims their update function on FIXED TIME SETUP, should be called exactly 60 **times per second**, in my emulator (or a blank XNA 4.0 refresh project), I've collected these values so far, using differect processors: AMD athlon 2x 6000 (the unsynced ones, that need an extra optimized update from AMD to run correctly) 60-61 tps. Intel i5 (2.8 i think) 55tps. On an old Lenovo laptop with a slow centrino 59-60tps (the desired one). Same goes for an old intel p4 hyperthreading; exactly 60 tps. On a DELL implementation (don't remember the cpu) it was 52-53 tps.
So what should I do. Timer's accuracy on seperate threads is horrible too. Besides, the update function will be called too in parallel (using almost 100% of the cpu).
Make a different profile for each cpu? (Assume that the tps, [times per second] counting is correct)

Answer (score 2):

The `Update` method calls are not [100% fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.isfixedtimestep.aspx). On a PC they *will try to be made* 60 times per second, but that depends on the machine and the logic of your game.

You can check if the system is working slower than it should by checking the `GameTime.IsRunningSlowly` property on your game ([link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.isrunningslowly.aspx)).

Also, you can modify the ticks it makes every second, for example a phone project starts with 33 ticks per second configured, against the 60 of a normal `Windows Game` project.

It would be wise to check [Shawn Hargreaves blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/07/25/understanding-gametime.aspx) about `GameTime`, it won't fix your problem but you will give you a better understanding of how the `Update` method works and maybe get an idea on how to fix the problem.

I quote part of his post here:

> By default XNA runs in fixed timestep mode, with a TargetElapsedTime
>   of 60 frames per second. This provides a simple guarantee: •We will
>   call your Update method exactly 60 times per second •We will call your
>   Draw method whenever we feel like it
>
> Digging into exactly what that means, you will realize there are
>   several possible scenarios depending on how long your Update and Draw
>   methods take to execute.
>
> The simplest situation is that the total time you spend in Update +
>   Draw is exactly 1/60 of a second. In this case we will call Update,
>   then call Draw, then look at the clock and notice it is time for
>   another Update, then Draw, and so on. Simple!
>
> What if your Update + Draw takes less than 1/60 of a second? Also
>   simple. Here we call Update, then call Draw, then look at the clock,
>   notice we have some time left over, so wait around twiddling our
>   thumbs until it is time to call Update again.
>
> What if Update + Draw takes longer than 1/60 of a second? This is
>   where things get complicated. There are many reasons why this could
>   happen:
>   1.The computer might be slightly too slow to run the game at the desired speed.
>   2.Or the computer might be way too slow to run the game at the desired speed!
>   3.The computer might be basically fast enough, but this particular frame might have taken an unusually long time for some reason. Perhaps
>   there were too many explosions on screen, or the game had to load a
>   new texture, or there was a garbage collection.
>   4.You could have paused the program in the debugger.
>
> We do the same thing in response to all four causes of slowness: •Set
>   GameTime.IsRunningSlowly to true. •Call Update extra times (without
>   calling Draw) until we catch up. •**If things are getting ridiculous and
>   we are too far behind, we just give up.**

If this doesn't help you, then posting some code showing what you think may be making the process slower would help.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know if this is irrelevant, but in a seperate uncapped loop, I get 400-450fps. This means 1 emulated machine clock executes in a mere 2.5ms max. Besides, I removed completely the CPU emulation, but it gave me the same result (61 fps). Concerning the IsRunningSlowly, I constantly have this ON in the Update function. But is 2-3ms delay long enough to turn it on? I mean, it would be normal for a programmer to add some time-consuming function in a game, but still expecting it to run at 60tps.

Comment: What do you mean you have the IsRunningSlowly on? The property is for the system to tell you if the update method is not being called properly, not the other way around!

Comment: Sorry, I will rephrase that. I check the IsRunningSlowly property of the Game class and it's true most of times :)

Comment: A typical mistake done with XNA is to draw everything on screen everytime, instead of what has changed from the previous Draw call, make sure you're not doing that.

Besides that, nothing comes to mind.

Comment: Actually the game was running slowly due to the output window showing  "True" all the time. I checked it a different way and now it's always false. Still though, the game runs at 60-61 fps, 55fps on i5, and 52fps on the DELL...